# Why is the error happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, babeljs

I'm following this tutorial [Full-stack Redux Tutorial](https://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html#the-architecture) and everything went well till the moment I had to run a local server (Starting under the title ***"Setting Up a Socket.io Server"***). I copied exactly what the tutorial shows and I'm getting this error when  running "npm run start"

[image]

As seen in the image, the command I'm trying to run is:

```
babel-node index.js
```

But the error says nothing I can catch, just that something is wrong with the command, not even with a file.

I'm lost and Google offers little help.

Comment: The error `EADDRINUSE` can be separated into: `E ADDR IN USE` which essentially means the port is already in use. Choose a different port.

Comment: I already changed the port several times, and the same is happening.

Comment: Please avail yourself of a Google search for EADDRINUSE.  Then, once you've read that if you still have questions you can come back here and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Something else is listening on port 3333 on your machine.  Change the port number to something else, and it should work.

If you told us what OS you were using, we could suggest how to determine *what* is listening on port 3333.

Comment: I already changed the port several times, and the same is happening.

Comment: @user1869935 In that case, you're probably listening twice.  Who knows though, you didn't show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's still a connection open on port `3333`. If you open `cmd` and run `netstat -a -b` you should be able to get a list of open connections together with the executables that started them.

It might be that your Socket.io server previously crashed and the exception wasn't handled properly, possibly leaving the connection open?